# clisp positive number founder

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to return a list which contains non-negative numbers from function parameter list using clisp.

```
(defun recursive (L)
    (setq ret (list)) 
    (setq first (car L))
    (setq rest (cdr L))
    (if (null L) 
        0 
        (if (>= first 0) 
            (nconc ret (first)) 
            (recursive rest))))

(setq mylist (list 1 2 3 -1 0 -3))
(write (recursive mylist))
```

I wrote this and expecting an output as `(1 2 3 0)`

What is wrong in that code?

Comment: 0 is a positive number?

Answer (score 3):

Let `filter` be the function you want to implement.
Then `(filter nil)` should return nil.
In the general case, you compte `(filter (number . tail))` recursively. Assuming that `filter` computes the list of positive numbers in a list, you can solve the problem for `tail`, and call `(filter tail)`. In order to solve your current problem, you have to consider if `number` is positive or not, and add the element to the recursive result accordingly.

```
(defun filter (list)
  (etypecase list
    (null nil)
    (cons (destructuring-bind (number . tail) list
            (if (plusp number)
                (cons number (filter tail))
                (filter tail))))))
```

I am using [`ETYPECASE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_tpcase.htm), [`PLUSP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_minusp.htm), [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm), but you can express the same differently. Note that you used [`NCONC`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) which requires iterating over the whole list, which is not required and makes your whole aproach quadratic in time.

The above function has a flaw because the size of the call stack grows linearly with the size of your input list. Each time you call filter, a new frame is allocated on the stack, which can be easily seen with [`TRACE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm):

```
CL-USER> (trace filter)
(FILTER)
CL-USER> (filter '(0 1 -2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9))

0: (FILTER (0 1 -2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9))
  1: (FILTER (1 -2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9))
    2: (FILTER (-2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9))
      3: (FILTER (3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9))
        4: (FILTER (-4 -5 6 7 -8 9))
          5: (FILTER (-5 6 7 -8 9))
            6: (FILTER (6 7 -8 9))
              7: (FILTER (7 -8 9))
                8: (FILTER (-8 9))
                  9: (FILTER (9))
                    10: (FILTER NIL)
                    10: FILTER returned NIL
                  9: FILTER returned (9)
                8: FILTER returned (9)
              7: FILTER returned (7 9)
            6: FILTER returned (6 7 9)
          5: FILTER returned (6 7 9)
        4: FILTER returned (6 7 9)
      3: FILTER returned (3 6 7 9)
    2: FILTER returned (3 6 7 9)
  1: FILTER returned (1 3 6 7 9)
0: FILTER returned (1 3 6 7 9)
```

This happens because you need to remember each intermediate value of `number` across recursive calls, in order to `cons` them with a recursive result. If you could instead have done all your work before descending into a recursive call, then there would be no need to retain intermediate values, and the function would be recursive terminal and *could* be subject to what is known as *tail-call optimization*. 
In order to do that, you have to build the resulting list before calling the recursive call, through an accumulator:

```
(defun filter (list accumulator)
  (etypecase list
    (null accumulator)
    (cons (destructuring-bind (head . tail) list
            (if (plusp head)
                (filter tail (cons head accumulator))
                (filter tail accumulator))))))
```

Notice the repetition, which can be refactored as:

```
(filter tail (if (plusp head) (cons head accumulator) accumulator))
```

Here above, we added an `accumulator`, which holds the new list. Initially, you should pass an empty list. When you reach the end of your input list, you return the accumulator. Otherwise, you add the number to the accumulator before calling `filter` recursively. The difference is that you don't need to store intermediate values in the call stack. The trace macro produces this:

```
0: (FILTER (0 1 -2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9) NIL)
  1: (FILTER (1 -2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9) NIL)
    2: (FILTER (-2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9) (1))
      3: (FILTER (3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9) (1))
        4: (FILTER (-4 -5 6 7 -8 9) (3 1))
          5: (FILTER (-5 6 7 -8 9) (3 1))
            6: (FILTER (6 7 -8 9) (3 1))
              7: (FILTER (7 -8 9) (6 3 1))
                8: (FILTER (-8 9) (7 6 3 1))
                  9: (FILTER (9) (7 6 3 1))
                    10: (FILTER NIL (9 7 6 3 1))
                    10: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
                  9: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
                8: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
              7: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
            6: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
          5: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
        4: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
      3: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
    2: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
  1: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
0: FILTER returned (9 7 6 3 1)
```

Please note that the function is tail-recursive, but doesn't look like it was optimized away because there is an arrow-shaped trace. However, trace is not a reliable way of knowing if the function is or isn't tail-recursive, because the act of tracing changes hat is actually done. Or, maybe the `debug` quality is so high that tail-call optimization is not applied. This depends on your implementation. Please note that the trace clearly shows how the intermediate list is built, and how the result is passed unchanged from deep levels to higher ones. See also that the list is being built in reverse, because we keep calling `cons` with the accumulator (which is efficient, contrary to nconc).
Since you didn't specify if you want the elements of the list to retain the same order as the input list, I  assumed  that this is not required.

However, you could also call [`NREVERSE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) on the resulting list to reverse it destructively (i.e. in-place, without allocating memory). This is ok if here because you *own* the fresh list being built, so you can safely modify it before giving it to the caller. This is best done by wrapping the implementation detail inside a local function:

```
(defun filter (list)
  (labels ((filter (list accumulator)
             (etypecase list
               (null accumulator)
               (cons (destructuring-bind (head . tail) list
                       (filter tail (if (plusp head)
                                        (cons head accumulator)
                                        accumulator)))))))
    (nreverse (filter list nil))))
```

Note that `filter` is lexically bound to a local function inside the global `filter` function. See also [`LABELS`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm).

However, you can better spend your time than writing recursive functions to perform loops. Common Lisp provide iteration construction, which means you can simply do this:

```
(defun filter (list)
  (loop for number in list
        when (plusp number)
          collect number))
```

Note that removing elements from lists is also easily done with [`REMOVE-IF-NOT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm).

Answer (score 1):

First off, your code doesn't work, because of the way you are using `first` as a function (`(first)`) in the then-branch of your `if`.

Apart from that, every time you call `recursive`, you re-initialize `ret` to an empty list. And inside the `if` you only recurse if the number is *not* bigger than 0.

Here's a working solution using `cond`:

```
(defun filter-non-negative (l)
   (cond
    ((null l)                   ;; empty list
     nil)
    ((>= (first l) 0)      ;; number >= 0
     (cons (first l) (filter-non-negative (rest l))))
    (t                         ;; all other cases 
     (filter-non-negative (rest l)))))

(write (filter-non-negative '(1 2 3 -1 0 -3)))
;; (1 2 3 0)
```

Comment: what for is the IF?

Comment: what does the name FILTER-POS mean?

Comment: @Sylwester I have and at least where I tested it it works: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lisp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclAwb0lEOS10MEk

Comment: @RainerJoswig The `IF` was a leftover from refactoring the original code. I'll remove it now. And `FILTER-POS` means "filter positive".

Comment: I would also replace NOT with NULL.

Comment: If it is FILTER-POSITIVE, then why is the zero kept? ;-)

Comment: Btw., that brings up a rare case: `(filter-positive '(-0.0 0.0 +0.0 0.1 -0.1 +0.1))  --->  
(-0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.1)`    This is in ABCL.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback re `NOT` and `NULL`, it's been years since I did CL. As for the semantics of positive number, I think we've argued the point enough :-) I'll rename it to `FILTER-NON-NEGATIVE`, as that seems to be the OP's intent based on example output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the variables `ret`, `first` and `rest` should be defined locally with a `let`. In your version they are global variables. Note that you don't need these variables at all, you can simply use the function calls directly.
In the line before last, you have `(first)`, which will signal an error because this function expects an argument. However, what you want is not the function `first` but the variable `first`, therefore you need `(list first)`. 
When the list is null, you return a 0. Since you will reach this point at the end of every recursive call, this will add a 0 to any input argument. You should return nil instead.
Finally, instead of `nconc` look at the function `cons`.

Incidentally, note that there is a function `remove-if` that will do exactly the job you want, but I understand that you are trying to learn about recursive calls.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the positive numbers. Positive numbers are greater 0.

Let's remove all numbers which are not positive:

```
CL-USER 24 > (remove-if-not #'plusp (list 1 2 3 -1 0 -3))
(1 2 3)
```

or

```
CL-USER 25 > (remove-if (complement #'plusp) (list 1 2 3 -1 0 -3))
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Note that what PTS eeker wants is the non-negative numbers, i.e. positive and zero. Your solution will remove negative AND zero. You should use instead remove-if #'minusp

Comment: So you chose to answer the admittedly wrongly phrased title over the the actual expected output?

Comment: @MichaelKohl: I was not sure what was wrongly phrased, the question in the title or his interpretation of it... I just picked one.